# PayPal how to set the subtotal attribute from the application

Tags: jsf-2, paypal

I'm developing a web application based on JSF 2.0. The application automatically generates a quote to sell a service so, the subtotal it's not predictable.

I would like to integrate PayPal Payments but I need to set the subtotal value in a dynamic way. I succeeded in doing payments of a fixed amount through the payPal sandbox using the standard integration of the HTML button. I also tried to add to the form that contains the generated button the subtotal value but it doesn't seem to work.
Something like:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"></input>
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="3V8S6DNHUQ58C"></input>
    <input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="88"> </input>
    <input type="image"
        src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/it_IT/IT/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
        name="submit"
        alt="PayPal - Il metodo rapido, affidabile e innovativo per pagare e farsi pagare."></input>
    <img alt="" border="0"
        src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/it_IT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1"
        height="1"></img>
</form>
```

Is there a way to set subtotal value from the application with HTML standard integration, preferentially getting the value from a bean property?
Do I have to use a more advanced way for the integration? Thanks for help, as usual.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button you're currently using is a hosted button.  As such, you cannot dynamically adjust it the way you want to.

You would have to edit your button and disable the "save at PayPal" option in order to make it a non-hosted button.  This way you would have direct access to the actual request parameters and you could adjust their values accordingly.

That said, it's not very secure because then users can see your button code, copy it, and adjust it before making a payment with it.

I would recommend you use the [Express Checkout API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec) instead.  This consists of [SetExpressCheckout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/setexpresscheckout-api-operation-nvp), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getexpresscheckoutdetails-api-operation-nvp), and [DoExpresscheckoutPayment](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/doexpresscheckoutpayment-api-operation-nvp).  This is a little bit more involved because you're working with web services, but it opens you up to customize it however you need and is secure.

Comment: Thanks, I was just considering to use Express Checkout API!